# Register screen won't successfully segue to a new view controller.

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, viewcontroller

Good afternoon. I am trying to implement a register feature into my application. When I successfully register, it will segue to the main view controller, however, it will just redirect back to the register view controller. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (User, error) in

```
        if error != nil {
            print("error")
            return
        }else{
            let MainView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController())
            self.present(MainView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        self.defaults.set(false, forKey: "user is logged in")

        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

        let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://odd-jobs-llc-f854a.firebaseio.com/")
        let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(userID)
        let values = ["first name": firstname, "last name": lastname, "phone number": phonenumber,
        "email": email]
        usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

            if err != nil {
                print("err")
                return
            }

            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        })


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will present the VC

```
 let MainView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController())
 self.present(MainView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and this

```
 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

will dismiss it , you may mean something like this

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (User, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("error")
            return
        } 

        self.defaults.set(false, forKey: "user is logged in")

        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

        let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://odd-jobs-llc-f854a.firebaseio.com/")
        let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(userID)
        let values = ["first name": firstname, "last name": lastname, "phone number": phonenumber,
        "email": email]
        usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

            if err != nil {
                print("err")
                return
            }

             let MainView = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController())
             self.present(MainView, animated: true, completion: nil)


        })


    }
}
```